# Python: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str : variable stored wrong

Tags: python, scripting

Hi Need clarification for python variable stored as wrong value , here is code :

```
userinput1 = int(input('enter start value\n'))
userinput2 = int(input('enter stop value\n'))
userinput3 = int(input('enter rampup time in seconds\n'))
userinput4 = float(input('enter  increments delta \n'))
userinput5 = input('Enter sequence channels: A A A A or D D D D - A Ascend, D Descent , E Exclude \n')
command1 = "RAMP " + str(userinput5) + " " + userinput1 + " " + userinput2 + " " + userinput4 + " " + userinput3
port.write(command1.encode())


#### ERROR #####

command1 = str("RAMP " + str(userinput5) + " " + userinput1 + " " + userinput2 + " " + userinput4 + " " + userinput3)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Can you please clarify me correct method to store both type variable input in single variable command. type caste was done already.

Comment: `userinput1` should be `str(userinput1)`, etc if you're concatenating it to a string. But that's unnecessary if you use f-strings: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#supporting-full-python-expressions

Comment: You need to decide what your `userinput` variables are: numbers or strings. Then use them consistently.

Comment: If you have the latest python you can use format strings rather than doing `str()`: `command1 = f'RAMP {userinput5} {userinput1} {userinput2} {userinput4} {userinput3}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concate only strings, so before concate all your userinputs you must "convert" them into strings

Example1:

```
command1 = "RAMP " + " ".join(map(str, [userinput5, userinput1, userinput2, userinput4, userinput3]))
```

Example2:

```
command1 = f"RAMP {userinput5} {userinput1} {userinput2} {userinput4} {userinput3}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped :)